# filter by part number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-loc

let say I have ID parameter

```
ID=[20020,54125,45698,54220]
```

I want to filter only numbers that have "20" in ID.

```
20020
54220
```

whats the best way to do that?
`

```
ID=[20020,54125,45698,54220]

df = pd.DataFrame(ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [656]: df[df[0].astype(str).str.contains('20')]
Out[656]: 
       0
0  20020
3  54220
```

**Note**: As per @Jonas' comment, Here `0` is the name of column.

Comment: Worth noting that `df[0]` in this case refers to the column name, which is the default is none is provided.

Comment: thank you, that help ...             a=df[df['id'].astype(str).str.contains('20')]

Answer (score 3):

You can also filter the list before making it a dataframe:

```
ID = [20020, 54125, 45698, 54220]
ID = list(filter(lambda x: "20" in str(x), ID))

df = pd.DataFrame(ID)
```

Here `lambda x: "20" in str(x)` is like an inline funtion which accepts the element as an argument checks whether the string `"20"` is `in` the stringified argument and returns the result.